# Localising progress dialogs

Tags: android, localization, progressdialog

I show a progress dialog with an asynchronous task.

```
private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    RetrieveTask t = this;
    ProgressDialog d = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        // TODO
        //d = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getString(R.string.querying_server), true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        d = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                t.cancel(true);
        }
        });
    // continues....
```

By this stage `context` has been set to the root activity.

I'd like to localise the message as indicated in the comment following the "TODO". To do this I need to get at the strings resource; how do I best do this from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm missing a `getResources()` call, that's all.

`context.getResources().getString(R.string.my_string_id);`

Answer (score 0):

I just use a reference to the calling activities context.

Example pseudo-code:

```
    public class MyMainActivity extends Activity {

    private void MethodA{
        new RetreiveTask().execute();
    }

   //then in the AsyncTask, you could get a context by using the: *MyMainActivity.this* syntax.

    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        RetrieveTask t = this;
        ProgressDialog d = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // TODO
            //d = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getString(MyMainActivity.this.R.string.querying_server), true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            d = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    t.cancel(true);
            }
            });

    }



    }
```

Comment: Thanks. However the task is not conducted in an activity it's aware of.